# Console app or web app

Tags: c#

I am creating a c# app that will run on a server. This app doesn't have any UI.
It does the following:

- Stream in a PDF file when the application is called.
- Modify the footer of the PDF (creating a few temp files along the way that are stored on the same server as the app).
- Stream the new version of the PDF back to the user with the appropriate HTTP headers to indicate it's a PDF.

My question is: Do I need to create this project as a C# web app? Or can it be a simple console application?

Comment: How about just a web/rest service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create C# console app which will be installed on server and provide back end functionality.
But you can also do this with web app.
Third there is "WPF" concept which changes the web layout to desktop/console application.

Comment: Thanks. That's all I was wondering. Not sure why my question got so much hate.